# Notification when a photoGallery/DocumentPicker is opened from the iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller, phpickerviewcontroller, uiimagepicker

I have a requirement where I need my sdk to be notified when the user in the host app opens a system UI such as PHPickerViewController/UIImagePickerViewController/UIDocumentPickerViewController etc. and once notified need to perform some action in the sdk. Is there any system triggered notification already available that gets triggered when such system UI is displayed in the app ?

I have checked to see if any app lifecycle event gets triggered when these viewcontrollers are opened in the app but found that none of them gets triggered at this point.